# Zapier - Create Array from Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, zapier

​
Hello, appreciate your insight on this.

### Overview

I’m looking for advice on how to output multiple objects from an array using JavaScript and the Code by Zapier app. So far I’ve been able to pull the data from the array’s string by using the `.split()` method and to output a single object using the mapped data, but I have not been able to create multiple objects and output them as a new array.

### The code

```
// My inputData looks like this:
 inputData = INFO [ 'Name1', 'Surname1', 'xxxx@gmail.com', 'phone1', 'Name2', 'Surname2', 'yyyy@gmail.com', 'phone2', 'Name3', 'Surname3', 'zzzz@gmail.com', 'phone3' ]

const participants = inputData.records.split(',')

let i = 0
// Look for every fourth item in the array starting at 0, which represents the participant's First Name
const getName = function(participants, i) {
  for ( i ; i < participants.length; i+=4 ) {
       let name = participants[i]

         return name
    }
  };
// Look for every fourth item in the array starting at 1, which represents the participant's Last Name
const getSurname = function(participants, i) {
  for ( let i = 1; i < participants.length; i+=4 ) {
       let surname = participants[i]

        return surname
    }
  };
// Look for every fourth item in the array starting from 2, which represents the participant's Email Address
const getEmail = function(participants, i) {
  for ( let i = 2; i < participants.length; i+=4 )  {
       let email = participants[i]

        return email
    }
  };

// Output an object inside an array with the key/value pairs as follows
output = {participants: [
{
  first_name: getName(participants, i),
  last_name: getSurname(participants, i),
  email: getEmail(participants, i)
}
]};
```

### An example output:

```
participants:
   1:
     first_name: Name1
     last_name: Surname1
     email: xxxx@gmail.com
```

If I log the output, it correctly shows that an object has been created:

`{first_name: 'Name1', last_name: 'Surname1', email: 'xxxx@gmail.com'}`

### My struggle

I’m struggling to find a way to iterate on the inputData and provide the records as follows:

```
participants:
   1:
     first_name: Name1
     last_name: Surname1
     email: xxxx@gmail.com
   2:
     first_name: Name2
     last_name: Surname2
     email: yyyy@gmail.com
   3:
     first_name: Name3
     last_name: Surname3
     email: zzzz@gmail.com
```

When I `console.log()` each function's output, I get each record from the `for` loops. Why does it not output a record for each then?

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to get the desired output like this:

```
const participants = inputData.records.split(',');
const size = participants.length;

// This sets up the iterator according to the lenght of the 'participants' array
class Sequence {
    constructor( start = 0, end = Infinity, interval = 1 ) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.interval = interval;
    }
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        let counter = 0;
        let nextIndex = this.start;
        return  {
            next: () => {
                if ( nextIndex <= this.end ) {
                    let result = { value: nextIndex,  done: false }
                    nextIndex += this.interval;
                    counter++;
                    return result;
                }
                return { value: counter, done: true };
            }
        }
    }
};

let range = new Sequence(0, size - 4, 4);

// Creates an array from the generated Sequence which sets up the iteration count
const startIndex = Array.from(range)

// Create a 'participant' object using the formula
const participant = function(arr, num) {
  let name = participants[num]
  let surname = participants[num+1]
  let email = participants[num+2]
  return {name: name, surname: surname, email: email}
};

// creates an empty array and then pushes the data with every cycle
let participantRecords = []
const participantsList = startIndex.forEach(function(num){
  participantRecords.push(participant(participants, num))
});

                                
output = {participantRecords}
```